# how to set user and owner password for PDF using ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript

i know his question has been asked many times so far but no solution was able to provide the correct syntax and parameters for the ghostscript that able to secure the pdf with owner and user passwords, also the encryption used,I've used the below commands but no one seems to work :

```
gswin64   -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=d:/sec/result.pdf -sOwnerPassword=string -f d:/sec/sunday.pdf
gswin64   -dBATCH -sOutputFile=d:/sec/result.pdf -sOwnerPassword=string -f d:/sec/sunday.pdf
gswin64   -dNOPAUSE  -dPermissions=3 -sOwnerPassword=string sOutputFile=d:\sec\result.pdf d:\sec\tt.pdf
```

am i missing any parameter ?

Answer (score 4):

For me this works:

```
gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOwnerPassword=password -sOutputFile=out.pdf test.ps
```

Acrobat reports the file has security 'password security', Page Extraction not allowed, everything else is allowed.

Same for :

```
gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOwnerPassword=password -sOutputFile=out.pdf test.pdf
```

How exactly are you testing whether the document is encrypted ?

Answer (score 2):

Again the thread is old and the other answers didn't work for me. What worked in 2020 was this:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -SPDFPassword=<filepasswordhere> -sOutputFile=<output_pdf_file> <input_pdf_file>`

For example: a file named `myfile.pdf` has a password set to `1234` and we want to save it to `mynewfile.pdf`. Then, the full command line would be:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -SPDFPassword=1234 -sOutputFile=myfile.pdf mynewfile.pdf`

GS version:

```
$ gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.50 (2019-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2019 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

**Update in 2023-09-28:**

I took a random unprotected pdf file and password-protected it with this command:

`qpdf --encrypt user-password owner-password 256 -- input.pdf out.pdf`

At this point, in order to open `out.pdf` with `evince`, I had to enter a password. Either `user-password` or `owner-password` worked, as expected.

I was able to remove the password protection with `gs` using either this:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -SPDFPassword=user-password -sOutputFile=unprotected.pdf out.pdf`

... or this:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -SPDFPassword=owner-password -sOutputFile=unprotected.pdf out.pdf`

Both commands worked straightaway here.

```
$ gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

**Update 2: trying to reply OP's original question:**

I'm adding this to complement my answer based on [K J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10802527/k-j)'s comment.

To **add** a password to a non-password-protected pdf document using `gs`, the process is very similar:

`gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=protected.pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sOwnerPassword=my-owner-password -sUserPassword=my-user-password -f unprotected.pdf`

Replace `my-owner-password` and `my-user-password` with the passwords you want to use.

Comment: Good point. I believe by the time I read the question I thought the OP was wanting to *remove* the password from a PDF file. I edited my answer and added the gs command to *add* a password to the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is not worked for me.

(I know it is a quite old thread. The question was asked in 2013 and it is now 2018. :D ) 
Do not know, but ghost script documentation is quite hard.

Ok. For me, my Ghostscript version looks like this.

```
manan@manan-EliteBook-8470p ~ $ gs -v
GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

The command which will work...

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dBATCH -dNOPROMPT -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -sOwnerPassword=mypassword -sUserPassword=manan -sOutputFile=MyOutputFile.pdf MyInputFile.pdf
```